# How to create integer out of array?

Tags: php, arrays

Is it possible to convert array values into one single integer. For example, I have array with numbers

```
$array = array(7,4,7,2);
```

Is it possible to get integer value 7472 from this array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple use **[`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)** as

```
$array = array(7,4,7,2);
echo (int)implode("",$array);// 7472
```

Comment: I suggest converting it to `(int)` so will be `(int)implode("",$array)` since by imploding it, it will make it a string.

Answer (score 2):

Use implode, which creates a string from an array. http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

`echo implode($array);`

Answer (score 2):

Use `implode` function as it create a string out of array and try this :

```
echo implode("",$array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `implode`, along with `(int)` to convert the string result to an integer:

```
$a = [7,4,7,2];
$res = (int) implode('', $a);
```

P.S. Since PHP 5.4 you can also use the short array syntax, which replaces array() with [].

Comment: Don't knon why negative marking for correct answer!!

Comment: My guess is that it looked more like a comment. I've edited it slightly.

Answer (score 0):

```
function digitsToInt($array) {
  $nn = 0;
  foreach ( $array as $digit) {
    $nn = $nn * 10 + intval($digit);
  }
  return $nn;
}
var_dump( digitsToInt(array(7,4,7,2)) ); # int(7472)
```